# Rails google-ads-ruby setting up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-ads-api

I am trying to use the [google-ads-ruby](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-ruby) library to allow our ruby on rails application users to connect our app with Google Ads and pull some stats from their account for them.
I installed the gem and managed to authenticate a user and get the refresh_token.

Now I'm trying to start collecting data from Google.

The first thing that fails is [their instructions](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-ruby#usage) to require the gem in my code with `require 'google/ads/google_ads'`
I tried adding it to my controller and got `cannot load such file -- google/ads/google_ads`

Then, according to [their instructions](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-ruby#set-up-authentication), I should be able to run this:

```
client = Google::Ads::GoogleAds::GoogleAdsClient.new do |config|
    config.client_id       = Rails.application.secrets.google_oauth_client_id
    config.client_secret   = Rails.application.secrets.google_oauth_client_secret
    config.developer_token = Rails.application.secrets.google_developer_token
    config.refresh_token   = @user.google_ads.refresh_token
end

accessible_customers = client.service.customer.list_accessible_customers().resource_names

accessible_customers.each do |resource_name|
    puts "Customer resource name: #{resource_name}"
end
```

and then list, for example, the user's accounts, [as described here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/account-management/listing-accounts).

However, I am getting `uninitialized constant Google::Ads::GoogleAds`

Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?

```
client = ::Google::Ads::GoogleAds::GoogleAdsClient.new do |config|
    config.client_id       = Rails.application.secrets.google_oauth_client_id
    config.client_secret   = Rails.application.secrets.google_oauth_client_secret
    config.developer_token = Rails.application.secrets.google_developer_token
    config.refresh_token   = @user.google_ads.refresh_token
```

end

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer to my question. I was unable to find a solution, but doing some more digging, I found the [AdsWords on Rails example app](https://github.com/googleads/google-api-ads-ruby/tree/master/adwords_api/examples/adwords_on_rails) Google added to that same gem and [the documentation](https://github.com/googleads/google-api-ads-ruby/wiki/AdWords-Rails-Demo)

The app is slightly outdated and you will probably hate getting it to work. Also, it's written in a very cryptic way and includes so many functions just to use their API... but I was able to make it work. To be honest, someone should write a tutorial.

Hope this may give some clues to someone who's lost at some point.